# NodeJS - running function to load in variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, loops, discord

I was wondering how I would go about making this function (`scrapData`) only run once, so that it doesn't increment each item and loads in all at once. Here's an image of what's happening in my CMD. I'm not very familiar with JS so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.[image]

And here is a snippet of code for that one command:

```
//latest articles command
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'latest')) {

    //website url variables
    const website_domain = "https://hypebeast.com/";
    let website_path = args[0];
    let website_url = website_domain + website_path;

    //extra arguments variable
    let extra_arg = args.slice(1).join(" ");

    //if user inputs too many arguments
    if (extra_arg.length > 0) {
        message.reply('too many arguments! Please refer to `h.help` for correct usage.');

    } else {
        
        //opening url and loading in websites html
        function scrapData(website_url) {
            return rp(website_url)
                .then(body => {
                    var items = [],
                        $ = cheerio.load(body);
                    
                    //web scraping here
                    $('.post-box').each(function() {
                        var title = $(this).find($('.title h2 span')).first().text(),
                            caption = $(this).find($('.post-box-excerpt p')).first().text(),
                            article_url = $(this).find($('.col-hb-post-image a')).first().attr('href'),
                            thumbnail_long = $(this).find($('.thumbnail img')).first().attr('src');
                        
                        //adding title, caption, etc to list
                        items.push({title, caption, article_url, thumbnail_long});

                        //check items in console
                        console.log(items);
                    })
                    return items;
                })
        }

        //run webscraping function
        scrapData(website_url)
            .then(items => {
                //produce embed messages
                for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    message.channel.send({
                        embed: {
                            color: config.embed_colour,
                            title: (i + 1 + ". " + items[i].title),
                            url: items[i].article_url,
                            description: items[i].caption,
                        }
                    })
                }
                message.channel.send("`SOURCE: " + website_url + "`");
                console.log('DONE!');
            })    
    }
    }
```

Comment: It's probably going somewhat better than you think. Each time you add an item to your 'items' array, you print that array(console.log(items)). Try printing the array once.(for example just before your `//produce embed messages` comment)

Comment: Does it request the website everytime it adds an item? or when it loops?
 @ate_f

Comment: Just when it loops. You're doing ` $('.post-box').each(function() {` the first part(` $('.post-box')`) retrieves an array of items, and then `.each` loops over it. You're doing `console.log(items)` for each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your function *is* only running once already. `scrapData` is only called once from code not in a loop or `each` statement (I assume the top of the code snippet is the beginning of the command). To decrease the amount of console messages logged consider moving the `console.log` call to the line right above the `return` statement.

As a direct response to your comment it only requests info from the website once, when you call `rp(url)`. The `then` body attached to that contains a loop that acts on the return from `rp`, but it has already completed its work (that's what the Promise guarantees: execute this *after* something else finishes). `cheerio` works completely offline and any data it works with is already fully downloaded at the time of execution, the name of the function it uses (`load`) is simply somewhat misleading in the context of your program. `rp` gets the body, `cheerio` is simply parsing it.